# Convert data- string into an object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Thinking along the lines of using language resources (especially in SharePoint), I want to bind the text of my HTML tags to a value in one of my resource JavaScript objects (SharePoint has a handler that will do this). I would like to do something like this:

HTML:

`<div id="helloMessage" data-stringResource="helloString" />`

JS:

```
  $('div').each(function() {
      $(this).text(SP.Publishing.Resources. + $(this).attr('data-stringResource'));
  });
```

Ideally, what I would want that to is in that text function pass in `SP.Publishing.Resources.helloString`. I think I can use `eval()` to accomplish this, but I read everywhere it's evil. Is there anything I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the square bracket form of the member operator.

```
$(this).text(SP.Publishing.Resources[$(this).attr('data-stringResource')]);
```

It uses the `toString()` value of whatever the expression in the brackets returns as the property name.

Comment: Thanks. I saw a similar looking topic but didn't put it together that you could use an object that way in JavaScript.